# Google time zone api For Android

Tags: android, google-maps, time, retrofit, zone

I've been trying to make use of the Google Maps Time Zone api in order to get the time zone and time offset from UTC for my Android app.  First I followed the [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro?hl=en) which seems pretty straightforward, it gave me no valid response, my request had a 200 code response but status REQUEST_DENIED, after lots of struggle with this  **I delete the Google API key component in the request and it worked!!**.

My application is in development process reason why I am testing it in a Genymotion emulator, which has google services up to date. Also I made the request by Retrofit 2.0.

Well, the google documentation says that API key has to be in the request but it works without it.  Does anyone know **why does this happen and if I continued, would it be working fine when the application is deployed in Google Play?, Should I use a different api to request what I need?**

I would really appreciate some advice, there is not much info about this topic.

Comment: i think when you created a project in the google developer console, you need to input the `package name` which is your app's identifier. So sometime you dont input the API key in your app, and google console can also let you go through.

Comment: Thanks Bjiang,  that is interesting, is not mentioned in the documentation. So far I've been hable to do the calls  without no problem. I hope is ok for deployment purposes.